# railway.app deployment goes without errors but when accessing the custom url am getting error as Application failed to respond

Tags: go, railway, pocketbase

Am deploying a PocketBase app in railway.app extending with Golang. Deployment is successful but when accessing Custom Domain it gives an error as Application failed to respond.

This is the code in main.go:

[main.go code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wYU9o.png)

I checked for multiple solutions but didn't find any

Comment: Please [don't post images of code](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/11810946). You will need to provide additional detail explaining [your configuration](https://docs.railway.app/deploy/exposing-your-app#custom-domains) (also worth stating explicitly if your app works when accessed via the [default domain](https://docs.railway.app/troubleshoot/fixing-common-errors)).

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the project, then creating it again.
This happened to me and I solved it this way